# Check if values are > 0 in a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this dataframe :

```
d =pd.DataFrame({'Values': [4, 5, 56, 5, 6, 35]})
```

And I want to print `True` if the last 3 values are `>0`

This is what I've done

```
d[-3:]>0
```

And I got

```
   Values
3   True
4   True
5   True
```

But this is not exactly what I want. I want to check the last 3 value and if they are all >0 then print True otherwise print False.

Thank you for the help

Comment: You can also use `all`  in answer below with `tail(3)` as alternative to indexing. `d.tail(3).all()>0` or `all(d.tail(3)>0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [all()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)

```py
(d[-3:]>0).all()
```